# Oracle db query - multiple questions regarding join and returning only latest date

Tags: sql, oracle, greatest-n-per-group

I have 2 tables, Inventory and Transactions
In Inventory i have columns Part_id, Location_Id and Zone_id (all VARCHAR)
In Transactions i have columns Part_id, Code and Date (Part_ID and Code are VARCHAR and Date is TIMESTAMP with local timezone)

I would like to see all Part_id, Location_id and Zone_Id from Inventory table and a column which would return latest date for Code 'Pick' for that Part_Id from transactions table if exists and if not, return a blank for that Part_ID.
Problem is that Tranasactions can match the Part_Id in Inventory with other Codes. So just going for inventory.part_id = transactions.part_id will not work.
And when there is no record for a Part_id with code Pick, how to get that returned...

```
Inventory:                       Transactions:

│Part_ID│Location_ID│Zone_ID│    │Part_ID│Code   │Date
│a001   │A          │Z      │    │a001   │Pick   │01/01/2017│
│b002   │B          │X      │    │b002   │Check  │01/02/2017│
│c003   │C          │Y      │    │c003   │Receive│05/02/2017│
│d004   │D          │Q      │    │d004   │Pick   │09/02/2017│
                                 │a001   │Pick   │11/02/2017│

Wanted result:

│Part_ID│Location_ID│Zone_ID│LatestDateofPick│
│a001   │A          │Z      │11/02/2017      │
│b002   │B          │X      │                │
│c003   │C          │Y      │                │
│d004   │D          │Q      │09/02/2017      │
```

I'm just a beginner with SQL so i'm kinda in square one with this, please be merciful. :)
Thanks for helping me out on this one!

Comment: Use an OUTER JOIN, MAX function and GROUP BY clause.

Comment: What I'd do is find the latest pick date per part_id in the transactions table (hint: an aggregate query would be suitable for this). Then it's a matter of simply outer joining that aggregated subquery back to the inventory table. Given that info, why not try writing the query for yourself? If you get stuck, update your question to include what you've tried and we'll help you from there

Answer (score 0):

You will need something like this to get what you are after

```
select t.Part_ID,
    i.Location_ID,
    i.Zone_ID,
    case when t.Code <> 'Pick' then null else max(t.Date) end as LatestDateOfPick
from Transactions t
join Inventory  i on t.Part_ID = i.Part_ID
group by t.Part_ID,i.Location_ID,i.Zone_ID,t.Code
```

This will pull the `max` date only when the Code it "Pick" otherwise it will leave it `NULL`

Answer (score 0):

I see this using an outer join and a max for the date

```
  -- Start test data
  with inventory (part_id, location_id, zone_id) as
       (select 'a001','A','Z' from dual union all
        select 'b002','B','X' from dual union all
        select 'c003','C','Y' from dual union all
        select 'd004','D','Q' from dual),
       transaction (part_id, code, txn_date) as 
       (select 'a001','Pick',to_date( '01-jan-17','DD-MON-RR') from dual union all
        select 'b002','Check',to_date( '02-JAN-17','DD-MON-RR') from dual union all
        select 'c003','Receive',to_date( '02-may-17','DD-MON-RR') from dual union all
        select 'd004','Pick',to_date( '02-sep-17','DD-MON-RR') from dual union all
        select 'a001','Pick',to_date( '02-nov-17','DD-MON-RR') from dual)
  -- end test data      
select inv.part_id,
       inv.location_id,
       inv.zone_id,
       MAX(txn.txn_date)
from inventory inv
     left outer join transaction txn on (inv.part_id = txn.part_id AND txn.code = 'Pick')
group by inv.part_id, inv.location_id, inv.zone_id;


"PART_ID"             "LOCATION_ID"         "ZONE_ID"     MAX(TXN.TXN_DATE)"           
"d004"                "D"                   "Q"           "09/02/2017 00:00:00"         
"c003"                "C"                   "Y"           ""                            
"a001"                "A"                   "Z"           "11/02/2017 00:00:00"         
"b002"                "B"                   "X"           ""
```